# Display outlook appointment calendar

Tags: c#, outlook, calendar, appointment

I have a C# app which creates an appointment (oAppoint) and moves it to a different calendar (an exchange one, not mine). When I use the `func() display()`, it displays the oAppoint object that is in my calendar. How do I display the appointment on the calendar I moved it to?

```
oAppoint.Move(newCalFolder);
oAppoint.Save();
oAppoint.Display(); // display the appointment item at the calendar I moved it to (? how ?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Move method will return an object referring to the item that was moved, so:

```
Outlook.AppointmentItem movedItem = (Outlook.AppointmentItem)oAppoint.Move(newCalFolder);
movedItem.Display();
```